# Terraform CLI : Error: Failed to read ssh private key: no key found

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this variable `private_key_path = "/users/arun/aws_keys/pk.pem"` defined in `terraform.tfvars` file

and i am doing `SSH` in my `terraform-template` . see the configuration below

```
connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = self.public_ip
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file(var.private_key_path)

  }
```

The private file is very much available in that path. But still i get the below exception thrown by the `terraform-cli`

> Error: Failed to read ssh private key: no key found

Is there anything else am missing out ?

Comment: What is your local OS running Terraform? What version of Terraform and how was it installed? Can you prove the file exists by showing us the listing such as `ls -al /users/arun/aws_keys/`? Can you test by removing the `terraform.tfvars` from the equation and just use the string?

Comment: Can you check that the content of your .pem file is valid for a private key?

Answer (score 0):

generate the public and private key using gitbash.

> $ ssh-keygen.exe -f demo

call the demo file or copy the demo and demo.pub file to the specific directory